# Why is גוי a preferred word than נוכרי to describe a non Jew?

Tags: words

It might be a cultural question rather than a religious one: but גוי is used to describe a nation (including the nation of Israel), גר is used to describe a Non Jew living is Israel and נכרי is used to describe a non Jew.

Yet it seems as if  the term גוי is the preferred term to describe a non Jew, why is that? (At least true in Yiddish and modern Hebrew)

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47762/akum-nochri-and-goy

Comment: Goy is a term of honor. Think about G-d’s blessing to Avraham. Nochri doesn’t have that connotation.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/86732/13438

Comment: @Alex so the origin of this ברכה, is the first significant mentioning of the word ״גוי״  in such a definition ?

Answer (score 2):

"Goy" has acquired a negative connotation only in modern times.  Nokhri (נָכְרִ) may also have a negative connotation.  It can be used for “enemy” [Deut. 32:27], “stranger who speaks harshly” [Gen. 42:7], “outsider” (בֶּן־נֵכָ֔ר -- ben nekhar) [Gen 17:12], “alien gods” [אֱלֹהֵ֤י הַנֵּכָר֙ – elohei hanekhar] [Gen. 35:2] but also to harmless refugees, laborers, visitors or businessmen.  I prefer just "non-Jew" myself.

Comment: So too Rabbi Yosef Karo who used  אינו יהודי in the Shulchan Aruch.

Comment: @Harel13, did he often? The Mishna Brura changed גוי and עכו"ם of previous editions to אינו יהודי.

Comment: @Mordechai That's what I remember from when I learned Hilchot Shabbat last year.